# Changing web host

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, ip, domain-name, ns-record

right now we host our website in an ISP which is also registers our domain.
the company now is entering a mobile operator business which requires that the website to be moved to our internal network to let the user use our website to access some services.

right now i'm still confused of what to do, what are the steps required to move the host and still alow the people when they type my company domain in the browser to be directed to the new location which is inside my company network , how the DNS NS Public IP issues has to be considered
?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First step: you need to become the controller of your domain name with the registrar.  This is something people forget to take care of, and it can leave in the dust for days if you don't pay attention to this.  Where have they registered your domain?  If your domain was registered at the web hosting ISP, then perhaps that needs to be transferred to a new registrar.  You'll need to work with both the new and old registrar to get this done.

Once you have control of the registrar set up and info, then you need to assign it the IP of the DNS server you will be running to handle DNS lookups of the domain.  Depending on the current type of commercial ISP you have for Internet access at your business, you might need an Internet connection upgrade to be able to host DNS and web services.  What DNS server you use and how to set it up is something I'm assuming you can handle, or we would need a small book (or a consultant) to answer or resolve your question.  From there you assign within DNS server, the IP of your web server or other services (MX) to the servers internal to your network which will run these.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a server on your internal network, copy your content over (you might also need to make sure you're running the same CMS internally.)  Then figure out how to allow access to that server on your internal network (maybe even put it on a DMZ.)  Then change the public DNS record to point to your server.

Given how you are asking this question, it sounds like you should hire a consultant for this.  I'd also ask this question: Do you need to move the whole website or can you create another sub-domain and use that?   www.example.com is your public website, mobileop.example.com runs your internal services.  mobileop.example.com could be run on a separate server on your internal network and wouldn't necessarily touch anything on your public one.

So many options.  Don't tell the consultant exactly what you want done, tell them what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate a little on what you mean by

> to let the user use our website to access some services.

If it's just **another** service, set up a new server inside a DMZ (ask your networking guy), configure it with a public IP or let your firewall do some NAT.

Name that new server whatever your service will be like, e.g. access.company.com and create a A-Record for it.